# New containing div after every 3 records

Tags: php, html, if-statement, while-loop

I would like to create a new containing `<div>` after 3 results, using PDO result loop.

For my self-study-project I have to made a product page with bootstrap and after every 3rd record I have to make a new row and show again 3 col-md-4's, etc, etc.

Now I have this as my code:

```
<div class="row">
    <?php
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
    ?>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="product">
                <div class="title"><?php echo $row->pname ?></div>
                <div class="img"><img
                    src="../product/img/<?php echo $row->pnumber ?>/<?php echo $row->pthumbnail ?>.jpg?$pop210x210$"/>
                </div>
                <div class="vijftien"></div>
                <div class="deliver">Levertijd: <strong><?php echo $row->pdelivertime ?></strong></div>
                <div class="vijf"></div>
                <div class="other"></div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="price"><?php echo $row->pprice ?></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="order">
                            <button class="log_in" id="doLogin">Meer informatie</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php } ?>
</div>
```

I have visited and studied other questions but I do not really get the idea of how they are doing it and how I can implement the correct method into my code.

Comment: Hint: `($row % 3) == 0` is true every three rows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As tadman stated in the comment under your question.  The best approach should use a [modulus operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php) (`%`) with `3`.

Place your separating condition at the start of each iteration.  ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/74a24f115fec724dbc148a59a73619e72f2f9a13))

Like this:

```
$x=0;  // I prefer to increment starting from zero.
       // This way I can use the same method inside a foreach loop on
       // zero-indexed arrays, leveraging the keys, and omit the `++` line.
echo "<div class=\"row\">";
    foreach($rows as $row){
        if($x!=0 && $x%3==0){  // if not first iteration and iteration divided by 3 has no remainder...
            echo "</div>\n<div class='row'>";
        }
        echo "<div>$row</div>";
        ++$x;
    }
echo "</div>";
```

This will create:

```
<div class="row"><div>one</div><div>two</div><div>three</div></div>
<div class='row'><div>four</div><div>five</div><div>six</div></div>
```

---

Late Edit, here are a couple of other methods for similar situations which will provide the same result:

```
foreach(array_chunk($rows,3) as $a){
    echo "<div class=\"row\"><div>",implode('</div><div>',$a),"</div></div>\n";
}
```

or

```
foreach ($rows as $i=>$v){
    if($i%3==0){
        if($i!=0){
            echo "</div>\n";
        }
        echo "<div class=\"row\">";
    }
    echo "<div>$v</div>";
}
echo "</div>";
```

---

To clarify what NOT to do...

Sinan Ulker's answer will lead to an unwanted result depending on the size of your result array.

Here is a generalized example to expose the issue:

Using this input array to represent your pdo results:

```
$rows=["one","two","three","four","five","six"];
```

Sinan's condition at the end of each iteration:

```
$i=1;
echo "<div class=\"row\">";
    foreach($rows as $row){
        echo "<div>$row</div>";
        if($i%3==0)echo "</div>\n<div class='row'>";  // 6%3==0 and that's not good here
        // 6%3==0 and will echo the close/open line after the content to create an empty, unwanted dom element
        $i++;
    }
echo "</div>\n\n";
```

Will create this:

```
<div class="row"><div>one</div><div>two</div><div>three</div></div>
<div class='row'><div>four</div><div>five</div><div>six</div></div>
<div class='row'></div>                          //<--- this extra element is not good
```

Comment: This is a good answer too, as well as the answer given before ^.    My situation now is that it is fixed with CSS. but this works too.

Answer (score -1):

You need to add a new closure tag and open new one every 3th iteration.

```
        <div class="row">
        <?php
        $sql  = "SELECT * FROM products";
        $stmt = $conn->query($sql);
        $stmt->execute();
        $i=1;
        while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {

            ?>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="product">
                    <div class="title"><?php echo $row->pname ?></div>
                    <div class="img"><img
                            src="../product/img/<?php echo $row->pnumber ?>/<?php echo $row->pthumbnail ?>.jpg?$pop210x210$"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="vijftien"></div>
                    <div class="deliver">Levertijd: <strong><?php echo $row->pdelivertime ?></strong>
                    </div>
                    <div class="vijf"></div>
                    <div class="other"></div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="price"><?php echo $row->pprice ?></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="order">
                                <button class="log_in" id="doLogin">Meer informatie</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php 
           if($i%3==0)echo "</div><div class='row'>";
           $i++; 
        } ?>
```

Comment: This answer will generate an extra/unwanted/empty containing element if the total rows is divisible by 3.  To see this flaw, follow the Demo link in my answer.

Comment: Thanks, this worked out great for me. I did fixed it too with css but I think this is a great way to do it too. Thanks!

Comment: @mickmackusa since it is choosed as answer i updated the code as you suggested. Thanks

Comment: @SinanUlker That is not okay.  That is stealing my answer and generating a late/duplicate post.

Answer (score -1):

$x = 0;
  echo "";

foreach($rows as $row)
{
    /* added one more condition for removing empty div.... */

```
if ($x != 0 && $x % 3 == 0 && $x < count($rows))
{
    echo "</div>\n<div class='row'>";
}

echo "<div>$row</div>";
++$x;
```

}

echo "";