# Split mysql results to 5 bootstrap grid

Tags: php, loops, grouping, bootstrap-grid

I am looking a way to show my mysql results to a 5 div with same numbers of rows.

Here what i did:

```
$query_1 = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM tables ORDER BY id ASC");
$all_cnt = array();
$i = 0;
while($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_1)) {
    $all_cnt[$i] = $rows["name"];
    $i++;
}

$all_cnt = array_chunk($all_cnt, 5);
$output = "";

foreach($all_cnt as $cnt) {
    $output .= '
            <div class="col-md-2 ">
              <div class="row content">
                <ul class="list-unstyled">
    ';
    foreach ($cnt as $t) {
       $output .= '<li>'.$t.'</li>';
    }
    $output .= '
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
    ';


}
```

But i get not ordered results and not same number on each grid !

Any other solution please ?

Comment: `5 div with same numbers of rows.`-> i am unable to understand this? are you using table?

Comment: Your question is Unclear.  Have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43566227/2943403  If this doesn't help you enough, you will need to clarify your coding intent and show us your expected result.